# jQuery - performing a function by adding a class?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, datepicker

In my MVC 2 application, I have many views with many, many input fields. Quite a lot of them contain DateTime variables.

I am using the datepicker jQuery plugin to help the user select the date. This also allows me to do the following in my MasterPage:

```
$(document).delegate(".hasDatepicker", "keyup", function () {
            this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.\/]/g, '');
});
```

This is to eliminate users from using incorrect characters if they prefer to type. Since Datepicker adds its own class to datepicker-elements, I was able ot use that class to automatically clean up input.
No issues here, This is the part that works like it should.

The problem however, is that when I open an Edit view, the Textbox is populated with "21/05/2012 0:00:00". Once you start using the Datepicker plugin, it gets changed to only the date, as it should.
To remove the Time-part from the textbox, I was thinking about doing:

```
$(".hasDatepicker").each( function() {
     $(this).val($this.val().replace(" 0:00:00",""));
});
```

Which seems to me to be the easiest solution.

But then I would have to add it to every page, and I was wondering if there is a way to make a .delegate() version of this. Something along the lines of

```
$(document).delegate(".hasDatepicker", SOME_EVENT, function () {
            $(this).val($this.val().replace(" 0:00:00",""));
});
```

The problem is, what should SOME_EVENT be? I want this to be triggered when the "hasDatepicker" class has been added, so that I know which textboxes to clear (there are other textboxes for remarks etc that also contain that string, but these should **not** be replaced.

Is there such an event that triggers on class change?
Or any other way to solve this without me having to copy paste it on every page? :)

Comment: Do the users need to be able to type in the textboxes? Could you force them to always use the JQuery datetime picker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do you use this complex way to edit the date format when jQuery datepicker has a builtin functionality doing just that using the dateFormat option:

fro jquery ui docs:

> The format for parsed and displayed dates. This attribute is one of
>   the regionalisation attributes. For a full list of the possible
>   formats see the formatDate function.
>
> Code examples
>
> ```
> Initialize a datepicker with the dateFormat option specified.
> $( ".selector" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
> Get or set the dateFormat option, after init.
> //getter
> var dateFormat = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat" );
> //setter
> $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd' );
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use formatting on server, so the time part won't get populated into the textbox. Like: `new DateTime().ToShortDateString()` or by creating a special format for this.

You can just use `EditorFor` like described [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/02/05/mvc-2-editor-template-with-datetime.aspx)

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid question, but does that work if you use "Html.TextBoxFor(x=> x.StartDate, ..." ? The problem is that I'm not populating the textboxes, MVC is doing that for me :) And Entity Framework is holding the StartDate variable, so if I had to do it by hand I would have to add vars to my Model and manually add and retrieve them from there?

Comment: Use `Html.EditorFor(x=>x.StartDate, ...)` and create a custom EditorTemplate for `DateTime` (like described in the link in my answer)